# Django error: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have done the following signal in my project:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=group1)
@disable_for_loaddata
def total_closing_group1(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):
    total_group_closing_deb_po = instance.master_group.filter(ledgergroups__Closing_balance__gte=0,balance_nature='Debit').aggregate(the_sum=Coalesce(Sum('ledgergroups__Closing_balance'), Value(0)))['the_sum']
    total_group_closing_deb_neg = instance.master_group.filter(ledgergroups__Closing_balance__lt=0,balance_nature='Debit').aggregate(the_sum=Coalesce(Sum('ledgergroups__Closing_balance'), Value(0)))['the_sum']
    total_group_closing_po_cre = instance.master_group.filter(ledgergroups__Closing_balance__gte=0,balance_nature='Credit').aggregate(the_sum=Coalesce(Sum('ledgergroups__Closing_balance'), Value(0)))['the_sum']
    total_group_closing_neg_cre = instance.master_group.filter(ledgergroups__Closing_balance__lt=0,balance_nature='Credit').aggregate(the_sum=Coalesce(Sum('ledgergroups__Closing_balance'), Value(0)))['the_sum']
    total_closing_deb_po = instance.ledgergroups.filter(Closing_balance__gte=0,group1_Name__balance_nature='Debit').aggregate(the_sum=Coalesce(Sum('Closing_balance'), Value(0)))['the_sum']
    total_closing_deb_ne = instance.ledgergroups.filter(Closing_balance__lt=0,group1_Name__balance_nature='Debit').aggregate(the_sum=Coalesce(Sum('Closing_balance'), Value(0)))['the_sum']
    total_closing_cre_po = instance.ledgergroups.filter(Closing_balance__gte=0,group1_Name__balance_nature='Credit').aggregate(the_sum=Coalesce(Sum('Closing_balance'), Value(0)))['the_sum']
    total_closing_cre_ne = instance.ledgergroups.filter(Closing_balance__lt=0,group1_Name__balance_nature='Credit').aggregate(the_sum=Coalesce(Sum('Closing_balance'), Value(0)))['the_sum']
    if total_group_closing_deb_po != None and total_group_closing_neg_cre != None and total_closing_deb_po != None and total_closing_cre_ne != None:
        instance.positive_closing = total_group_closing_deb_po + abs(total_group_closing_neg_cre) + total_closing_deb_po + abs(total_closing_cre_ne)
    if total_group_closing_po_cre != None and total_group_closing_deb_neg != None and total_closing_cre_po != None and total_closing_deb_ne != None:    
        instance.negative_closing = total_group_closing_po_cre + abs(total_group_closing_deb_neg) + total_closing_cre_po + abs(total_closing_deb_ne)
```

My models are:

```
class Group1(models.Model):   
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)    
    master = models.ForeignKey("self",on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='master_group',null=True)    
    negative_closing = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,default=0,decimal_places=2,null=True)    
    positive_closing = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,default=0,decimal_places=2,null=True)


class Ledger1(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    group1_name     = models.ForeignKey(Group1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,related_name='ledgergroups')
    closing_balance = models.DecimalField(default=0.00,max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,blank=True)
```

It was working fine in the beginning but all of a sudden when I am increasing the load of the database by putting datas into fields.

It is throwing me the error `[<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]`.

What this error implies?

Any idea anyone

Thank you

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24636 Please, read this thread. I think this is what you exactly need.

Comment: Yes this is the exact solution but how to safely use this decimal validator without changing the built-in files in a django project

Comment: ```negative_closing = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,default=0,decimal_places=2,null=True)``` create custom validator for your decimal fields.

Comment: is the problem is with `max_digit` and `decimal_places`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem and what I have done to solve it is to make sure that the value I want to save fits in the field, two things:

1. First, use `round(myValueFloat, 4)`. It is, to reduce the number of decimal numbers I try to save.
2. Use bigger fields for the values I can not reduce.

Answer (score 22):

I recently got this problem myself. The way I thought I knew about decimal fields was wrong in my case.

I thought max_digits=x gives x values for the integer part and decimal_places=y gives y values for the decimal part but I was wrong.

max_digits define the total no. of digits overall and decimal places are part of the max_digits.

for eg. if `max_digits=13` and `decimal_places=3` then the field will store numeric values up to a billion with 3 precise decimals.

This may help someone who got stuck as I did for the past few hours.

Comment: I think you accidentally misspoke. A numeric value up to 1 billion with 3 decimal places be max_digits=13 and decimal_places=3, right?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought I made it clear instead I mistyped it by mistake. Thanks for letting me know. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I was getting this when using Faker via FactoryBoy to generate decimals. Faker uses left_digits and right_digits. In Django, left_digits + right_digits should not exceed max_digits of the field, and ideally, right_digits should be the same as the decimal_places.

Comment: @Anjaan - I did the same mistake in understanding. Thanks for figuring it out