# Weird error produced when querying sqlite databased using a model

Tags: python, django

I'm getting a very weird `decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]` when trying to query a table in my Django application. I suspect it may be related to the virtual environment.

This is the view. It is an endpoint that will receive some JSON data (at the moment I'm using Postman to send data to it).

```
def handleRawMarketData(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        print(data)
        for item in data:
            new_data = rawMarketData(duration=item['duration'],
                                     is_buy_order=item['is_buy_order'],
                                     issued = item['issued'],
                                     location_id = item['location_id'],
                                     min_volume = item['min_volume'],
                                     order_id = item['order_id'],
                                     price = item['price'],
                                     range = item['range'],
                                     typeID = InvTypes.objects.get(typeID = 
                                     item['type_id']),
                                     volume_remain = item['volume_remain'],
                                     volume_total = item['volume_total'])
        
            new_data.save()

        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Data saved successfully'})
    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Failed'})
```

This is the data being sent in the body of the POST request by Postman:

```
[{"duration":90,"is_buy_order":true,"issued":"2023-10-03T10:21:32Z","location_id":1038457641673,"min_volume":1,"order_id":6512967679,"price":17720000,"range":"region","type_id":19255,"volume_remain":2,"volume_total":3},{"duration":90,"is_buy_order":true,"issued":"2023-10-17T20:31:19Z","location_id":1038457641673,"min_volume":1,"order_id":6616121350,"price":500.2,"range":"station","type_id":24509,"volume_remain":198250,"volume_total":200000}]
```

These are the two models being used.

```
class InvTypes(models.Model):
    typeID = models.IntegerField(db_column='typeID', primary_key=True)
    groupid = models.IntegerField(db_column='groupID', blank=True, null=True)
    typename = models.CharField(db_column='typeName', blank=True, null=True, max_length=10000)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    mass = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    volume = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    capacity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    portionsize = models.IntegerField(db_column='portionSize', blank=True, null=True)
    raceid = models.IntegerField(db_column='raceID', blank=True, null=True)
    baseprice = models.DecimalField(db_column='basePrice', max_digits=10, decimal_places=5, blank=True, null=True)  
    published = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    marketgroupid = models.IntegerField(db_column='marketGroupID', blank=True, null=True)
    iconid = models.IntegerField(db_column='iconID', blank=True, null=True)
    soundid = models.IntegerField(db_column='soundID', blank=True, null=True)
    graphicid = models.IntegerField(db_column='graphicID', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'invTypes'
```

And this one:

```
class rawMarketData(models.Model):
    duration= models.IntegerField()
    is_buy_order = models.BooleanField()
    issued = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    location_id = models.IntegerField()
    min_volume = models.IntegerField()
    order_id = models.IntegerField(unique=False)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    range = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    typeID = models.ForeignKey(InvTypes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    volume_remain = models.IntegerField()
    volume_total = models.IntegerField()
    entry_created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And this is the traceback for the error:

```
[{'duration': 90, 'is_buy_order': True, 'issued': '2023-10-03T10:21:32Z', 'location_id': 1038457641673, 'min_volume': 1, 'order_id': 6512967679, 'price': 17720000, 'range': 'region', 'type_id': 19255, 'volume_remain': 2, 'volume_total': 3}, {'duration': 90, 'is_buy_order': True, 'issued': '2023-10-17T20:31:19Z', 'location_id': 1038457641673, 'min_volume': 1, 'order_id': 6616121350, 'price': 500.2, 'range': 'station', 'type_id': 24509, 'volume_remain': 198250, 'volume_total': 200000}]
Internal Server Error: /hello/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bhaalgorn/.local/share/virtualenvs/evemarketreader-django-LUolK3dd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/bhaalgorn/.local/share/virtualenvs/evemarketreader-django-LUolK3dd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/bhaalgorn/Documents/GitHub/evemarketreader-django/backend/views.py", line 20, in handleRawMarketData
    typeID = InvTypes.objects.get(typeID = item['type_id']),
  File "/home/bhaalgorn/.local/share/virtualenvs/evemarketreader-django-LUolK3dd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bhaalgorn/.local/share/virtualenvs/evemarketreader-django-LUolK3dd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 633, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/bhaalgorn/.local/share/virtualenvs/evemarketreader-django-LUolK3dd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/bhaalgorn/.local/share/virtualenvs/evemarketreader-django-LUolK3dd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1881, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/bhaalgorn/.local/share/virtualenvs/evemarketreader-django-LUolK3dd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 121, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "/home/bhaalgorn/.local/share/virtualenvs/evemarketreader-django-LUolK3dd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1500, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, connection)
  File "/home/bhaalgorn/.local/share/virtualenvs/evemarketreader-django-LUolK3dd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py", line 342, in converter
    return create_decimal(value).quantize(
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
```

#EDIT 1

I tried querying the same item from the InvTypes using the shell, and things got even weirder. This is what I did:

```
>>> from backend.models import InvTypes
>>> InvTypes.objects.get(typeID=19255).typename
>>> 'Gistum A-Type EM Shield Amplifier'
```

So it works for an `typeID=19255` and it returns 'Gistum A-Type EM Shield Amplifier'.

But when I do this:

```
>>> InvTypes.objects.get(typeID=24509)
```

I get the same error as the one above.

Comment: Does `24509` exist in your table?  You may need to set a default value other than "blank".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56458774/4046632 check also link referenced in the comments

Comment: Yup `24509` definitely exists in the table. I manually checked the `.sqlite` file.